# C# complicated regex

Tags: c#, regex

Hey guys, thanks for all the help that you can provide. I need a little bit of regex help thats far beyond my knowledge.

I have a listbox with a file name in it, example 3123~101, a delimited file that has 1 line of text in it.  I need to Regex everything after the last "\" before the last "-" in the text file.  The ending will could contain a prefix then ###{####-004587}.txt  The ~ formula is {### + ~# -1.

File name:
3123~101
So Example 1:
3123|X:directory\Path\Directory|Pre0{0442-0500}.txt

Result:
X:\directory\Path\Directory\Pre00542.txt

File name:
3123~101
So Example 1:
3123|X:directory\Path\Directory|0{0442-0500}.txt

Result:
X:\directory\Path\Directory\00542.txt

Comment: That is one bizar requirement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static string AdjustPath(string filename, string line)
{
  int tilde = GetTilde(filename);

  string[] fields = Regex.Split(line, @"\|");

  var addbackslash = new MatchEvaluator(
    m => m.Groups[1].Value + "\\" + m.Groups[2].Value);
  string dir = Regex.Replace(fields[1], @"^([A-Z]:)([^\\])", addbackslash);

  var addtilde = new MatchEvaluator(
    m => (tilde + Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value) - 1).
           ToString().
           PadLeft(m.Groups[1].Value.Length, '0'));

  return Path.Combine(dir, Regex.Replace(fields[2], @"\{(\d+)-.+}", addtilde));
}

private static int GetTilde(string filename)
{
  Match m = Regex.Match(filename, @"^.+~(\d+)$");

  if (!m.Success)
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid filename", "filename");

  return Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Call `AdjustPath` as in the following:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine(AdjustPath("3123~101", @"3123|X:directory\Path\Directory|Pre0{0442-0500}.txt"));
  Console.WriteLine(AdjustPath("3123~101", @"3123|X:directory\Path\Directory|0{0442-0500}.txt"));
}
```

Output:

```
X:\directory\Path\Directory\Pre00542.txt
X:\directory\Path\Directory\00542.txt
```

If instead you want to write the output to a file, use

```
public static void WriteAdjustedPaths(string inpath, string outpath)
{
  using (var w = new StreamWriter(outpath))
  {
    var r = new StreamReader(inpath);
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
      w.WriteLine("{0}", AdjustPath(inpath, line));
  }
}
```

You might call it with

```
WriteAdjustedPaths("3123~101", "output.txt");
```

If you want a `List<String>` instead

```
public static List<String> AdjustedPaths(string inpath)
{
  var paths = new List<String>();

   var r = new StreamReader(inpath);
   string line;
   while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
     paths.Add(AdjustPath(inpath, line));

   return paths;
}
```

To avoid repeated logic, we should define `WriteAdjustedPaths` in terms of the new function:

```
public static void WriteAdjustedPaths(string inpath, string outpath)
{
  using (var w = new StreamWriter(outpath))
  {
    foreach (var p in AdjustedPaths(inpath))
      w.WriteLine("{0}", p);
  }
}
```

The syntax could be streamlined with Linq. See [C# File Handling](http://dotnetperls.com/file-handling).

Comment: Thanks, i'll give this a go.  How do I even use this though?

Comment: I need to add this under the private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) section.

Comment: Yeha I can figure out how to write this out to a text file.

Comment: I cant figure out, it keeps giving me cannot convert from method group to string

Comment: How do you also write the result out to a text file

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The only thing is all the values are being read in from a text file.  and how would i call this under.  private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: This a Winform i do appricate th ehelp.

Comment: You defiently got the answer!!!  If I wanted to make a string of the resulting Adjustedpaths how would you set it up string blah = adjustedpaths?

Answer (score 3):

According your example I've created the following regexp:

```
\|(.)(.*)\|(.*)\{\d{2}(\d{2})\-(\d{2}).*(\..*)
```

The result should be as following:

```
group1 + "\\" + group2 + "\\" + group3 + group5 + group4 + group6
```

If you ain't satisfied, you can always give it a spin yourself [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

---

EDIT:

After remembering me about named groups:

```
\|(?<drive>.)(?<path>.*)\|(?<prefix>.*)\{\d{2}(?<number2>\d{2})\-(?<number1>\d{2}).*(?<extension>\..*)

drive + "\\" + path + "\\" + prefix + number1 + number2 + extension
```

Comment: I would have used named groups, but all the same :)

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on gbacon's answer that will also work in older versions of .Net:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Adjust("3123~101", @"3123|X:directory\Path\Directory|Pre0{0442-0500}.txt"));
        Console.WriteLine(Adjust("3123~101", @"3123|X:directory\Path\Directory|0{0442-0500}.txt"));
    }

    private static string Adjust(string name, string file)
    {
        Regex nameParse = new Regex(@"\d*~(?<value>\d*)");
        Regex fileParse = new Regex(@"\d*\|(?<drive>[A-Za-z]):(?<path>[^\|]*)\|(?<prefix>[^{]*){(?<code>\d*)");

        Match nameMatch = nameParse.Match(name);
        Match fileMatch = fileParse.Match(file);

        int value = Convert.ToInt32(nameMatch.Groups["value"].Value);

        int code = Convert.ToInt32(fileMatch.Groups["code"].Value);
        code = code + value - 1;

        string drive = fileMatch.Groups["drive"].Value;
        string path = fileMatch.Groups["path"].Value;
        string prefix = fileMatch.Groups["prefix"].Value;

        string result = string.Format(@"{0}:\{1}\{2}{3:0000}.txt",
            drive, 
            path,
            prefix, 
            code);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: One day my boss will allow the upgrade, but I'm still waiting :-(

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be very clear in your examples.

That said,

```
/.*\\(.*)-[^-]*$/
```

will capture all text between the last backslash and the last hyphen in whatever it's matched against.